# How can I have multiple CASE in select statements in PL/SQL function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a function that has 2 case statements. For background, a user can have either an A, B, or both A and B (but on separate lines, which is why I can't use a single case statement, unless I use LISTAGG, which I was told not to do for this.

Sample Data:

```
User State 
1       A 
1       B 
2       A 
3       B
```

SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function F_Calc_State(code Varchar2, id Number, time varchar2) Return Varchar2 AS

    Calc_State(10) := null;

    l_A varchar2(10) := null;
    l_B varchar2(10) := null;

BEGIN

    SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'A' THEN 'A'
                ELSE null 
           END into l_A,   
           CASE WHEN state = 'B' THEN 'B'
                ELSE null 
           END into l_B
      FROM TABLE1
     WHERE state in ('A', 'B')
       AND TABLE1_CODE = code
       AND TABLE1_ID   = id
       AND TABLE1_TIME = time;

    CASE WHEN l_A = 'A' and l_B = 'B' then 'AB'
         WHEN l_A = 'A' THEN 'A'
         WHEN 1_B = 'B' THEN 'B'
         ELSE stafford_recip_ind :='NEITHER';
    END CASE;

    RETURN Calc_State;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        RETURN 'NO DATA';
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        RETURN SQLERRM ;
END  F_Calc_State;`
```

For wanted results, when I enter user 1, I want AB to be returned, for user 2 = A, and user 3 = B. I also tried having two different select statement blocks but couldn't get that to work either, it would just hit the exception handler for some reason.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand how "loops" work (in computing in general, not necessarily in PL/SQL)? In your code, you loop over the rows in the base table - over the rows with the specified id and time values, and state in 'A', 'B'. These rows are read and processed ONE AT A TIME, there is no connecting back between different iterations. In the case of id = 1, one of the rows is read first (you don't know - you can't know - which one is read first unless you add an ORDER BY, but that won't help anyway). One variable is set to 'A' (or to 'B', depending on which row is read first) and the other to null.

Comment: Then the **next** row in the cursor is read, all the variables are OVERWRITTEN, `calc_state` is calculated using the last values of the variables. No "memory" of what happened for the first row when the variables are assigned to again for the **second** row. And the function will return whatever the value happens to be after the last iteration of the loop. This is why you will never get the desired result this way.

Comment: The better question is, why are you trying to do this in PL/SQL in the first place? A trivial (and many times faster) solution is to do it all in a simple SQL statement. Even if you need to write a function, you can simply select the concatenation of status (A and/or B) into a single variable and return it. Or is this specifically just an exercise to practice PL/SQL coding?

Comment: I am familiar with loops from a conceptional standpoint and so I appreciate your explaining how it works in the specific example. In this example though,  I am passing in a unique ID, along with the table constraints (state in ('A','B')) so I would assume this would work for ID = 1 as it is populating 2 variables within one 'loop'. Although from others it looks like I can't use 2 'into' statements. As far as why, this is something that are end users are going to be able to use themselves in order to figure out what state their users are in. Also Thanks!

Comment: It's `select x, y into x1, y1 from whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code would return `NULL` if no data is found:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function F_Calc_State (
    in_code Varchar2,
    in_id Number,
    in_time varchar2  -- "time" as a string is highly suspicious
) Return Varchar2 
AS
    v_ab varchar2(10) := null;
BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t1.state = 'A' THEN 'A' END) ||
           MAX(CASE WHEN t1.state = 'B' THEN 'B' END)
    INTO v_AB
    FROM  TABLE1 t1
    WHERE t1.state in ('A', 'B') AND
          t1.TABLE1_CODE = in_code AND
          t1.TABLE1_ID = in_id AND
          t1.TABLE1_TIME = in_time;    
    RETURN(v_ab);
END;  -- F_Calc_State
```

However, this does not return return an error if no data is found.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function F_Calc_State (
    in_code Varchar2,
    in_id Number,
    in_time varchar2  -- "time" as a string is highly suspicious
) Return Varchar2 
AS
    v_ab varchar2(10) := null;
BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t1.state = 'A' THEN 'A' END) ||
           MAX(CASE WHEN t1.state = 'B' THEN 'B' END)
    INTO v_AB
    FROM  TABLE1 t1
    WHERE t1.state in ('A', 'B') AND
          t1.TABLE1_CODE = in_code AND
          t1.TABLE1_ID = in_id AND
          t1.TABLE1_TIME = in_time;  
    GROUP BY t1.TABLE1_CODE;  -- this will return no rows if there are no matches

    RETURN(v_ab);

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN 'NO DATA';
        WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN SQLERRM ;

END;  -- F_Calc_State
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, especially the suspicious 'time' as varchar. I actually renamed that to 'time period' which has letters in it....long story. Regarding your code, it works and I never would have though to have concatenate the 2 case statements. Also, I have no idea what the max() does in this. Can you provide a brief explanation of that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, Now you will get only a single row of result.

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'A' THEN 'A'
                ELSE null END),    
       MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'B' THEN 'B'
                ELSE null END)
INTO l_A, l_B
FROM TABLE1
 WHERE state in ('A', 'B')
   AND TABLE1_CODE = code
   AND TABLE1_ID   = id
   AND TABLE1_TIME = time;
```

Comment: You can only have one `into` statement in a select. Also I think the OP would want to follow this with `Calc_State := nvl(l_A || l_B, 'NEITHER');`

Comment: @kfinity . . . The double `into` statement is taken from the OP's code.  It is wrong and should have been fixed, but the comment is perhaps better directed to the OP.

Comment: So for clarification, I can't have a double into statement in one select statement? I can't GauraS's solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

A very trivial approach could be this:
It's not clear if you want to check for existance of records or not, as in your exception block you return "NO DATA" while in your case statement you have the value "NEITHER".. anyway, you can adjust this accordingly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function F_Calc_State( code varchar2
                                       , id number
                                       , time varchar2
                                       ) return varchar2 
as
  l_count_a number;
  l_count_b number;
  l_result varchar2(10);

begin

  select count(*)
    into l_count_a
    from table1
   where state = 'A'
     and table1_code = id
     and table1_time = time;

  select count(*)
    into l_count_b
    from table1
   where state = 'B'
     and table1_code = id
     and table1_time = time;

  if    l_count_a = 0 and l_count_b = 0 then l_result := 'NEITHER'; 
  elsif l_count_a > 0 and l_count_b = 0 then l_result := 'A';
  elsif l_count_a = 0 and l_count_b > 0 then l_result := 'B';
  elsif l_count_a > 0 and l_count_b > 0 then l_result := 'AB';
  else  l_result := '';
  end if;

  return l_result;
end F_Calc_State;
```

Comment: This worked. I wrote nearly the same thing but with case statements (in both of the 2 separate select blocks, as well as case at the bottom similar to your 'if...then' statement. However, I couldn't get it to work. When a user would be either A or B it would jump to the exception handler.  I  assumed because it wasn't using one of the two select statements. But this doesn't seem to suffer from that problem. Thanks!

Comment: Typical exceptions you get when running SQLs inside PLSQL are NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS.
Both of them won't get raised with the way I made the SQLs: I am using a count() as aggregate function. That way you'll not have a NO_DATA_FOUND (but just 0 as value) nor won't you have to worry about TOO_MANY_ROWS. Therefore I have no exception handler at all here.